Cannot Update Data in MySql (error: ER_PARSE_ERROR)
I'm trying to make the "Edit Profile" page so a user can edit his/her profile info. But I screwed up somewhere and It is not working. I am assuming that I did a mistake in the query part.
My controller (API):
export const editUser = (req, res) => {
  const q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?";
  const userId = req.params.userId;

  db.query(q, [userId], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(409).json(err);

    const q = "UPDATE users SET (`name`, `surname`, `headline`) VALUES (?)";
    const values = [req.body.name, req.body.surname, req.body.headline];

    db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
      if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
      return res.status(200).json("User has been updated.");
    });
  });
};

My route (API):
const router = express.Router();
router.post("/edit-profile/:userId", editUser);

export default router

My client site code:
  const [err, setErr] = useState(null);
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({ name: "", surname: "", headline: "" });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputs((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
    console.log(inputs);
  };

  const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:8800/api/users/edit-profile/" + userId, inputs);
    } catch (err) {
      setErr(err.response.data);
    }
  };

HTML:
          <form action="a">
            <div>
              <p>Name:</p>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={error ? "Something Went wrong" : isLoading ? "Loading" : data.name}
                name="name"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>Surname:</p>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={error ? "Something Went wrong" : isLoading ? "Loading" : data.surname}
                name="surename"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>Headline:</p>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={error ? "Something Went wrong" : isLoading ? "Loading" : data.headline}
                name="headline"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
          </form>

To make it simpler I tried to POST in Insomnia :
{
    "name": "asd",
    "surname": "asd", 
    "headline": "asd"
}
 

But I am getting an error:
{
    "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
    "errno": 1064,
    "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`name`, `surname`, `headline`) VALUES ('asd', 'asd', 'asd')' at line 1",
    "sqlState": "42000",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "UPDATE users SET (`name`, `surname`, `headline`) VALUES ('asd', 'asd', 'asd')"
}

I want to edit the user name, surname, and headline of a user.

The code line const q = "UPDATE users SET (`name`, `surname`, `headline`) VALUES (?)"; contains SQL code which is synthactically wrong. See UPDATE syntax.

The update statement doesn't have a values clause, a series of column=value parts. You're also missing a where clause there to update only the user you got the ID for:
const q = 
    "UPDATE users SET `name` = ?, `surname` = ?, `headline` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
const values = [req.body.name, req.body.surname, req.body.headline, userId];


I am getting this error.
http://localhost:8800/api/users/edit-profile/9 500 (Internal Server Error)
handleClick @ UmcProfileBar.jsx:32
And the UmcProfileBar.jsx's 32 line is:
`  const handleClick = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
try {
  await axios.post("http://localhost:8800/api/users/edit-profile/" + userId, inputs); //  the 32nd line
} catch (err) {
  setErr(err.response.data);
}

};`

@TadashiHaneda catch the error and print it out. There's no useful information in the snippet you shared

I used the "Try{}Catch{}" that is what it is reporting. I am sorry if I didn't understand, I am new to this (I think you already got it)
